EVMError: Revert for Auction.sol
Building an Auction for ERC20 Tokens.
Scripts are compiling.
2/3 tests pass.
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] for 1/3.
It may be an issue with the OpenZeppelin import, it may be out of date, wrong import path, or something else. I am unable to resolve.
Auction.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";

contract Auction {
    address public owner;
    IERC20 public token;
    uint256 public auctionEndTime;
    uint256 public totalTokens;
    bool public auctionEnded;

    mapping(address => uint256) public bids;
    mapping(address => bool) public bidders; // Track bidders
    address[] public bidderList; // List of bidders

    event AuctionStarted(uint256 duration, uint256 totalTokens);
    event BidPlaced(address indexed bidder, uint256 amount);
    event AuctionEnded(address indexed winner, uint256 amount);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the contract owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier auctionActive() {
        require(block.timestamp < auctionEndTime, "Auction has ended");
        require(!auctionEnded, "Auction already ended");
        _;
    }

    modifier auctionEndedOnly() {
        require(
            block.timestamp >= auctionEndTime || auctionEnded,
            "Auction still active"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; // Set contract deployer as owner
    }

    function startAuction(
        address _token,
        uint256 _duration,
        uint256 _totalTokens
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            auctionEndTime == 0 || block.timestamp >= auctionEndTime,
            "Previous auction not ended"
        );
        token = IERC20(_token);
        require(
            token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _totalTokens,
            "Not enough tokens for auction"
        );
        auctionEndTime = block.timestamp + _duration;
        totalTokens = _totalTokens;
        auctionEnded = false;
        emit AuctionStarted(_duration, _totalTokens);
    }

    function placeBid() external payable auctionActive {
        require(msg.sender != owner, "Owner cannot place bids");
        require(msg.value > 0, "Bid must be greater than 0");

        bids[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        bidders[msg.sender] = true; // Register the bidder
        bool isNewBidder = true;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bidderList.length; i++) {
            if (bidderList[i] == msg.sender) {
                isNewBidder = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isNewBidder) {
            bidderList.push(msg.sender);
        }
        emit BidPlaced(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function endAuction() external onlyOwner auctionEndedOnly {
        require(!auctionEnded, "Auction already ended");
        console.log("Auction not ended, proceeding");

        auctionEnded = true;
        uint256 totalBidAmount = address(this).balance;
        require(totalBidAmount > 0, "No bids placed");
        console.log("Total bid amount:", totalBidAmount);

        uint256 tokenDistributed = 0;
        console.log("Number of bidders:", bidderList.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bidderList.length; i++) {
            address bidder = bidderList[i];
            uint256 tokenAmount = (bids[bidder] * totalTokens) / totalBidAmount;
            console.log("Bidder", i, ":", bidder);
            console.log("Bid amount:", bids[bidder]);
            console.log("Token amount to distribute:", tokenAmount);

            if (tokenAmount > 0) {
                require(
                    token.transfer(bidder, tokenAmount),
                    "Token transfer failed"
                );
                console.log("Tokens transferred to bidder");
                emit AuctionEnded(bidder, tokenAmount);
                tokenDistributed += tokenAmount;
            }
            bids[bidder] = 0; // Clear the bid amount
        }

        require(
            tokenDistributed <= totalTokens,
            "Distributed more tokens than available"
        );
        console.log("Total tokens distributed:", tokenDistributed);

        uint256 etherToTransfer = address(this).balance;
        console.log("Ether to transfer to owner:", etherToTransfer);
        payable(owner).transfer(etherToTransfer);
        console.log("Ether transferred to owner");
    }

    function withdrawRemainingTokens() external onlyOwner auctionEndedOnly {
        uint256 remainingTokens = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(
            token.transfer(owner, remainingTokens),
            "Token transfer failed"
        );
    }
}


Auction.t.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "../src/Auction.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MockERC20 is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Mock Token", "MKT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 10 ** 18);
    }
}

contract AuctionTest is Test {
    Auction public auction;
    MockERC20 public token;
    address public owner;
    address public bidder1;
    address public bidder2;

    function setUp() public {
        owner = address(this); // Test contract is the owner
        bidder1 = address(0x1);
        bidder2 = address(0x2);

        auction = new Auction();
        token = new MockERC20();

        // Transfer tokens to the auction contract
        require(
            token.transfer(address(auction), 100 * 10 ** 18),
            "Token transfer to auction failed"
        );

        // Approve the auction contract to spend tokens
        require(
            token.approve(address(auction), type(uint256).max),
            "Token approval failed"
        );

        // Verify the transfer and approval
        assertEq(
            token.balanceOf(address(auction)),
            100 * 10 ** 18,
            "Auction didn't receive tokens"
        );
        assertEq(
            token.allowance(address(this), address(auction)),
            type(uint256).max,
            "Approval failed"
        );
    }

    function testStartAuction() public {
        vm.prank(owner);
        auction.startAuction(address(token), 1000, 100 * 10 ** 18);

        assertEq(
            auction.totalTokens(),
            100 * 10 ** 18,
            "Total tokens mismatch"
        );
        assertEq(
            address(auction.token()),
            address(token),
            "Token address mismatch"
        );
    }

    function testPlaceBid() public {
        vm.prank(owner);
        auction.startAuction(address(token), 1000, 100 * 10 ** 18);

        vm.prank(bidder1);
        vm.deal(bidder1, 1 ether); // Ensure bidder1 has enough ETH
        auction.placeBid{value: 1 ether}();

        assertEq(auction.bids(bidder1), 1 ether, "Bid amount mismatch");
    }

    function testEndAuction() public {
        console.log("Starting testEndAuction");
        vm.prank(owner);
        auction.startAuction(address(token), 1000, 100 * 10 ** 18);
        console.log("Auction started");

        vm.prank(bidder1);
        vm.deal(bidder1, 2 ether);
        auction.placeBid{value: 2 ether}();
        console.log("Bidder1 placed bid");

        vm.prank(bidder2);
        vm.deal(bidder2, 3 ether);
        auction.placeBid{value: 3 ether}();
        console.log("Bidder2 placed bid");

        vm.warp(block.timestamp + 1001);
        console.log("Time warped to end of auction");

        uint256 initialOwnerBalance = address(owner).balance;
        uint256 initialAuctionBalance = address(auction).balance;
        uint256 initialTokenBalance = token.balanceOf(address(auction));

        console.log("Initial owner ETH balance:", initialOwnerBalance);
        console.log("Initial auction ETH balance:", initialAuctionBalance);
        console.log("Initial auction token balance:", initialTokenBalance);

        vm.prank(owner);
        auction.endAuction();
        console.log("Auction ended");

        uint256 bidder1TokenBalance = token.balanceOf(bidder1);
        uint256 bidder2TokenBalance = token.balanceOf(bidder2);
        uint256 finalOwnerBalance = address(owner).balance;
        uint256 finalAuctionBalance = address(auction).balance;
        uint256 finalTokenBalance = token.balanceOf(address(auction));

        console.log("Bidder1 token balance:", bidder1TokenBalance);
        console.log("Bidder2 token balance:", bidder2TokenBalance);
        console.log("Final owner ETH balance:", finalOwnerBalance);
        console.log("Final auction ETH balance:", finalAuctionBalance);
        console.log("Final auction token balance:", finalTokenBalance);

        assertEq(
            bidder1TokenBalance,
            40 * 10 ** 18,
            "Bidder1 token balance mismatch"
        );
        assertEq(
            bidder2TokenBalance,
            60 * 10 ** 18,
            "Bidder2 token balance mismatch"
        );
        assertEq(
            finalOwnerBalance,
            initialOwnerBalance + 5 ether,
            "Owner didn't receive ETH"
        );
        assertEq(
            finalAuctionBalance,
            0,
            "Auction contract should have 0 ETH balance"
        );
        assertEq(
            finalTokenBalance,
            0,
            "Auction contract should have 0 token balance"
        );
    }
}


Output
Ran 1 test suite in 814.65ms (66.59ms CPU time): 2 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (3 total tests)
Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/Auction.t.sol:AuctionTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testEndAuction() (gas: 380426)
Please advise.
Update:
Trace:
├─ [0] console::log("Ether to transfer to owner:", 5000000000000000000 [5e18]) [staticcall] │ └─ ← [Stop] ├─ [45] AuctionTest::fallback{value: 5000000000000000000}() │ └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

can you share the stack trace

@AdamBoudj
├─ [0] console::log("Ether to transfer to owner:", 5000000000000000000 [5e18]) [staticcall]
│   └─ ← [Stop]
├─ [45] AuctionTest::fallback{value: 5000000000000000000}()
│   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
└─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

I think you need to check the remapping or OpenZeppelin. If you've already done that, just import it like this
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";

I ran the script, and while I didn't get an EVM error, there was an assertion failed error

Thanks, it was an issue with the remapping and there was also a dependency conflict.
I reinstalled node/npm and imported openzeppelin-contracts IERC20.
